# Define "God's Acre"

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

What is meant by the phrase *God's acre*?

I searched and it was about location names. I'd like short description for it.

Comment: God's acre :n. a churchyard or burial ground.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/God's+acre

Comment: Pretty [easy to google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=god%27s+acre+definition) that or look it up in a dictionary, no?

Answer (score 2):

[*God's acre*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/God%27s+acre) is a name for a churchyard or burial ground.  It comes from the German "Gottesacker", which literally means "field of God". It has been in use since 1610–20. ( Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

It comes from a Christian belief that the dead will rise again after the second coming of Jesus Christ.  In this way, the deceased's bodies were being sewn like seeds in a field, and they would grow again after the return of Christ.

Comment: Please support your (completely correct) answer with a source. It becomes a stronger answer.